# VS 2017 keeps resetting font to Consolas 9

Tags: visual-studio

After the latest update (26403.3) which was pushed two days ago my VS 2017 keeps resetting all my monospaced fonts (Text Editor, XAML Designer, All Text Tools Windows etc.) to Consolas 9.

I keep changing it back to my preferred font and size and restarting IDE to attempt to persist changes but to no avail, it keeps resetting back to Consolas 9 even while the IDE is open and running. This never occurred until this latest update.

Did anyone else experience this, is it a bug, is it possibly being set by some new rogue extension, any idea how to prevent it?

Yes, I saved all my settings and now it's just a matter of re-importing the settings but it is still very annoying doing this couple of times a day...

I just restarted again and now my document tab well is gone and all the tabs are on top... something is really wrong with this update...

Comment: Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem.  And to make you feel better: Help > Send Feedback > Rate This Product.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, I was not aware of those advanced options, I thought it would make sense to check with the community to make sure others have the same problem before reporting it as a bug and submitting ratings didn't realize that was naive of me...

Comment: This stopped happening after I logged out of VS so give that a try if you have the same problem...

Comment: FWIW, I seem to have a similar problem in version 15.7.4 of VS2017 (over a year later than this question was written). It keeps resetting the "Text Editor" font to Consolas. I haven't yet figured out what is causing it, although looking around it may be related to having multiple instances of the IDE open.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I had two instances of visual studio 2019 open. After closing both, I only opened one instance, changed the font and opened the other instance as well. Now it seems to work!